# How do I share photos from a secret Facebook group?

Tags: privacy, facebook-groups, photo-sharing

Me and my friends have a secret Facebook group we use to share most of our photos.
We now post all of our photos in the secret group because it's just convenient.

But is there a way I can share a photo from the secret group to my wall, to share it with my other Facebook friends, without having to download and re upload the photo? Because doing so removes the likes and the comment thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the most efficient way to solve this problem is to use the native photo album feature from facebook.
When creating an album you can select who can all see the pictures, pictures that are then tagged are automatically shared with friends, this is a much more efficient approach then using groups.